# How to apply a function on several rows in a dataset using VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

first time question for me. I'm currently working on VB.Net and having some trouble with datasets. I have :

- A dataset "MyDataset" with 1 table in it.
- Table "MyTable" contains 5 rows and 1 column.
- The values of the rows are [2, 5, 6, 10, 12].

I want to apply a function that I need to define in .NET which computes the mean of all rows below row X including X.  I don't know how to:

- create a storage device for my outputed means
- define the arguments needed for my function
- apply my function to a group of rows.

I expect an output vector or range which would give me the mean of

- [2, 5, 6, 10, 12]
- [5, 6, 10 , 12]
- [6, 10 , 12 ]
- [10 , 12]
- [12 ]

My intended use is to plot that output on a graph later on. I'm guessing I need to use an Array to save my computed means.

Comment: Have you  written any code to attempt this?  If so, please post it and let us know details about what errors or unexpected output it is being returned.  If you haven't written any code, you might get a sentence or two on how to go about it, but Stack Overflow is not a free consulting (or homework) service, so it is highly unlikely that you're going to get much help with this until you have some code to show that you're working on it.  Someone will be glad to help when you have a specific problem instead of a general, "How do I write this program?"

Comment: I'll try to come up with a code example in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it on my own using a List. Here's the code I used:

```
Private Sub Compute_AvgTick()

    Dim MyDataSet As DataSet
    Dim MyQuery As String
    Dim DS_Count As Integer

    Dim MyList As New List(Of Double)
    Dim AvgList As New List(Of Double)

    MyQuery = "SELECT PL FROM TradeRegistry ORDER BY TradeNumber DESC "
    MyDataSet = Get_Dataset(MyQuery, "MyTable")     ' This function queries my database and gets my dataset

    DS_Count = MyDataSet.Tables("MyTable").Rows.Count

    For i = 0 To (DS_Count - 1)

        MyList.Add(MyDataSet.Tables("MyTable").Rows.Item(i).Item(0))
        AvgList.Add(MyList.Average())

    Next i

End Sub
```

I now have my List "AvgList" which contains every average I needed.